# How to Iterate through all nodes in XML file

Tags: asp.net, xmlreader

Hi I have xmlFile like  below .My  problem  is that  I cant iterate through all nodes.I have tried something like this .But I think its to diffucult for me .I am so cunfused

```
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
    {
        string xmlFile = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"myxml.xml";  
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();  
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;  
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("myxml.xml"), settings)) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                string xmlContent = "";
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Book") {

                    while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                    {
                        xmlContent += reader.ReadString().ToString();


                    }
                    Label1.Text = xmlContent;
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

> Myxml file something like this

```
         <books>
               <book>
                   <id>1</id>
                     <name>Photodex ProShow: Visual QuickStart Guide</name>
                      <author>Jon Canfield</author>
                      <price>$29.99</price>
                      <type>Photoshop</type>
                 </book>

             </books>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML and it as easy as a few lines to get all of the elements in the XML file, like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PathOfYourXMLFile.xml");

var allElements = doc.Descendants();
```

Note: `doc.Descendants()` returns a collection of `XElement` objects.

Now you can get the name of the each element, like this:

```
foreach(XElement el in allElements)
{
    var theName = el.Name;
}
```

Similarly, you can get the value of the each element, like this:

```
foreach(XElement el in allElements)
{
    var theValue = el.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Carl But I already have a Linq to xml sample about this tutorial .I wonder How to do with XmlReader